# How to trace which reference is used in jsonschema

Tags: json, validation, python-3.6, jsonschema, ref

TLDR: How do you determine which reference is being used during validation using jsonschema?

Using:

- Python 3.6.3
- jsonschema 2.6.0

I have defined schema that use two levels of reference. At each level, there are multiple references that can be followed for validation. How do I determine which reference was used to validate the provided json? What would a unit test look like to assert the correct references were used during validation? There may be some bugs in the below examples/code, sorry, I could not copy/paste an example.

I thought about increasing the logging level of the jsonschema module but I didn't see any logging objects in the source code.

The examples are stripped down from originals for brevity.

message.schema

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "properties": {
        "messagetype": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                { "$ref": "request.schema" },
                { "$ref": "response.schema" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [ "messagetype" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

request.schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "request": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": { "const": "food" },
                        "info": { "$ref": "food.schema" }
                    }
                },{
                    "properties": {
                        "name": { "const": "shelter" },
                        "info": { "$ref": "shelter.schema" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "required": [ "name", "info" ],
        "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "required": [ "requesttype" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

response.schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "response": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": { "const": "meal" },
                        "info": { "$ref": "meal.schema" }
                    }
                },{
                    "properties": {
                        "name": { "const": "house" },
                        "info": { "$ref": "house.schema" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "required": [ "name", "info" ],
        "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "required": [ "requesttype" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

food.schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "nomnoms": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [ "example" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

shelter.schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "material": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [ "material" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

meal.schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "contains": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [ "contains" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

house.schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "rooms": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [ "rooms" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

request_food_example.json

```
{
    "messagetype": {
        "request": {
            "name": "food",
            "info": {
                "nomnoms": "please give me a meal."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

request_shelter_example.json

```
{
    "messagetype": {
        "request": {
            "name": "shelter",
            "info": {
                "material": "brick"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

response_meal_example.json

```
{
    "messagetype": {
        "response": {
            "name": "meal",
            "info": {
                "contains": "all the vitamins and nutrients you need."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

response_house_example.json

```
{
    "messagetype": {
        "response": {
            "name": "house",
            "info": {
                "rooms": "3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

schema_validation.py

```
import json, jsonschema, argparse
from pathlib import Path

class JsonValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, schemafileinput, examplefileinput):
        self.schemafile = Path(schemafileinput).absolute()
        self.jsonfile = Path(examplefileinput).absolute()

        if not self.schemafile.exists() or not self.schemafile.is_file():
            raise ValueError("Bad schema file [{}]".format(self.schemafile))

        if not self.jsonfile.exists() or not self.jsonfile.is_file():
            raise ValueError("Bad example file [{}]".format(self.jsonfile))

    def validate(self):
        with open(schema) as f:
            schemadata = f.read()

        with open(jsonfile) as f:
            exampledata = f.read()

        schema = json.loads(schemadata)
        example = json.loads(exampledata)

        schemafile_directory = "{}/".format(self.schemafile.parent)

        resolver = jsonschema.RefResolver("file://" + schemafile_directory, schema)
        validator = jsonschema.validators.Draft4Validator(schema, resolver=resolver)

        try:
            validator.validate(example)
            print("Example json is valid")
        except Exception:
            errors = str()
            for error in validator.iter_errors(example):
                errors = "{}\n----------next error--------{}".format(errors, error)

            raise RuntimeException("Validation failed.\n{}".format(errors))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("jsonfile")
    parser.add_argument("schemafile")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    validator = JsonValidator(args.jsonfile, args.schemafile)
    validator.validate()
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, the "way you do this" currently, is to write your own implementation, or submit a pull request against the library you're using to add support to do so.

Comment: @Relequestual I was really hoping this would not be the case!!! I'm holding out for a possible solution...